# Import translation file only for specific core module

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am creating a multilingual D7 website. I am using core module locale and i18n contrib module. I am trying to import the localization files for a language.

I know that I can download the *unified .po file* for a language from https://localize.drupal.org and import it in the multilingual website from http://EXAMPLE.COM/admin/config/regional/translate/import.

Is there a way I can export from https://localize.drupal.org a .po file *only for a specific core module* (eg contact)? I can do this for a contrib module but not for a core module.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you cannot.

Translations are stored per project, not per module, and [core is one project](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/projects/drupal). Of course there is experimental [Contact project on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/project/contact), but it's [translation](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/projects/contact) stays pretty empty as it's not needed.

Worse, in exported files (at least [in my language](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/translations/7.x/drupal/drupal-7.23.pl.po)) there is no metadata, no comments about modules these strings originated. So manually cutting this file to your needs would be pretty hard, too.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that we cannot do anything or maybe we have to place a feature request at the Multilingual Initiative.

Comment: @TheodorosPloumis it seems that way. Sorry. Wasn't able to think about anything better than what I tested. Feature request seems reasonable.